# Console Value is repeating on each render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I am accessing data from database which is in the form of

[image: firestore collection of cars]

**chasis** is a unique identifier in the documument which is also used for **document ID**

1. In my snippet code i am getting data from firestore and passing that
   data in another component **cars.js**. I am using **map()** which allow me to render different car on every iteration
2. I am using **filter *useState*** which allow me to filter between two type of cars **local car** & **auction car** and that **filter** value is used in **useEffect** to filter data from firestore
3. I am passing **chasis** as **key** soo every chlid should have unique value
4. In **Cars.js** i am using **console.log(car.chasis)** But in my console in Chrome the console value is displayed two times on every render

List item

```
    function ShowCars() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const [filter, setFilter] = useState("local");
  const [cars, setCars] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    db.collection("cars")
      .orderBy("timestamp", "desc")
      .where("carType", "==", filter)
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) =>
        setCars(snapshot.docs.map((car) => ({ id: car.id, car: car.data() })))
      );
  }, [filter === "local"]);

  useEffect(() => {
    db.collection("cars")
      .orderBy("timestamp")
      .where("carType", "==", filter)
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) =>
        setCars(snapshot.docs.map((car) => ({ id: car.id, car: car.data() })))
      );
  }, [filter === "auction"]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <ButtonGroup color="primary" aria-label="outlined primary button group">
          <Button onClick={(e) => setFilter("local")}>Local</Button>
          <Button onClick={(e) => setFilter("auction")}>Auction</Button>
        </ButtonGroup>
      </div>
      {cars.map(({ id, car }) => (
        <Cars key={id} car={car} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default ShowCars;
```

Cars.js component snippet

```
import React from "react";

function Cars({ car, id }) {
  console.log(car.chasis);
  return (
    <div>
      {car.carType} id:{id}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Cars;
```

[image: Chrome Console]
I want to avoid the repetition of console value

Comment: Then you have to remove the console.log from the Cars component

Comment: {cars.length > 0 && cars.map....}, since you provide a default array you can check by length and then render if it has elements. This way you will prevent empty render for the first time. This could also be related to firebase itself, I remember having similar issue, where it was triggering twice the data fetch.

Comment: Can you add a working example here, if possible

Comment: You have an issue in use useEffect 2 times so show console 2 times you need to remove one time and try to manage query dynamically in only one useEffect method . Share code in codepan so I will change accordingly.

Comment: @sedhalsoni this idea is helpful and there is no duplicate console now  Why dont you answer it soo i can mark it ✅

Comment: @usamaabdulrazzaq. I have added the answer please mark as complete so useful for other peoples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used 2 times **useEffect** methods so you can try to add only one time and add query dynamically in only one useEffect method. You can change your code in the ShowCars component accordingly.

```
function ShowCars() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const [filter, setFilter] = useState("local");
  const [cars, setCars] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    db.collection("cars")
      .orderBy("timestamp", "desc")
      .where("carType", "==", filter)
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) =>
        setCars(snapshot.docs.map((car) => ({ id: car.id, car: car.data() })))
      );
  }, [filter]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <ButtonGroup color="primary" aria-label="outlined primary button group">
          <Button onClick={(e) => setFilter("local")}>Local</Button>
          <Button onClick={(e) => setFilter("auction")}>Auction</Button>
        </ButtonGroup>
      </div>
      {cars.map(({ id, car }) => (
        <Cars key={id} car={car} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default ShowCars;
```